# Make Chrome extension accessible to all the users of my Google Workspace domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-workspace

I published an extension to Chrome Web Store in private but I can't install it for all the users of my domain. I can only specify test users.

From the [documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=en):

> Private — Only users in your domain can see and install the app or extension. Or, you can restrict the app or extension to trusted testers that you specified in your developer dashboard.

Is the documentation no longer up to date ? Do I need to publish the extension in public ?

Comment: I've run into the exact same issue (and I've published private domain extensions before) and opened a support case with chrome webstore support. Once I hear back I'll post the response here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google recently changed how this works. There's a new setting inside Workspace where you need to enable the ability to publish to private domain extensions.

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9039146#webstorepermissions

Google Workspace Admin Console -> Devices -> Chrome -> Apps and Extensions -> Users & Browsers. Click the cog on the right for your policy (by default there's 1 already in there).

If necessary, select the proper OU on the left.

Scroll down and second from the bottom there's `Chrome Web Store permissions`. Change this to `Allow users to publish private apps`.

Go back to the chrome web store and the private domain option will now exist.

Comment: Lots of conflicting answers on this on Stack Overflow, this is what worked for me - thanks!